# What is the best way to send sequential queries to the server using Socket (Android)?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have two android devices, one acting as client and other acting as server. I am trying to get `n` number of images from the server device. Previously, to fetch just one image I was using `AsyncTask` to create and open a `Socket` connection on the client device. And a thread was running on the server device with `ServerSocket`. Both were configured to use the same port.

I want to query some images. Since the connection is on the same port, I don't think I can send those queries simultaneously? Is that possible?

I was thinking of creating a `Queue` of `AsyncTask` and execute them one by one. But after reading some of the posts regarding this, it seems that `AsyncTask` is no the right way to do this and there's a limitation over number of AsyncTask threads.

Android Developers website suggests that `IntentService` is useful to perform such tasks. So I wrote a basic class.

```
public class ClientSyncService extends IntentService {
    private JSONObject jsonData;
    private static final int SocketServerPORT = 4000;
    private String hostAddress;
    private Bitmap queryBitmap;
    private static final String TAG = "ClientSyncService";
    private String requestString;

    public ClientSyncService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        String jsonString = workIntent.getDataString();
        hostAddress = workIntent.getStringExtra("host-ipaddress");

        try {
            jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            requestString = jsonData.getString("request");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(hostAddress, SocketServerPORT);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                  socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(jsonData.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "waiting for response from host");

            if (requestString == null) {
                socket.close();
                return;
            }

            if (requestString == "query-display-picture" || requestString == "query-album-art") {
                Log.i(TAG, "waiting for image");
                byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int len;
                while((len = dataInputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(buf, 0, len);
                    bos.flush();
                }
                if (bos.size() > 0) {
                    queryBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bos.toByteArray(), 0, bos.size());
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "bitmap is null");
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "bitmap created");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // close socket and streams
        }

    }
```

I'll figure the rest of the part out regarding broadcasting the data to the activity. I'm unclear about how to call this `IntentService`. Do I prepare a queue and create new intent service for each image query or pass all the image requests to intent service and the service will have a loop and send request to the server and get data.

**TL;DR**: I want to get n number of images/files from client (preferably using the same port). What is the best way to do that? I have read about `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `BlockingQueue` but didn't try them out yet. I am a bit new to threading.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect several sockets from a client to the same host:port, that will just create more sockets on the server, you'll need multiple threads accepting the connections on the server.

Or a single AsyncTask could be created with a list of images to fetch and get them all one after the other. You could also make a single request for multiple images and get them all in the same socket (e.g. by sending size / data / size / data / ... or by using something as Google protocol buffers (a repeated field would be just fine).

Last option could be to have a worker thread getting requests in a queue (one request per image) and processing them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would be to get those images sequentially only.
But i think a normal java thread would be the best.

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask.